# Why is subtraction a stable operation?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen & Bau, it is claimed that subtraction is backward stable. Here is the proof:

Let $f(x, y) = x-y$ and let $\tilde f(x,y)$ be the answer you get when doing $x-y$ on a computer. We have $$\begin{align*}\tilde f(x, y) &= (x(1+\epsilon_1) - y(1 + \epsilon_2))(1 + \epsilon_3)\\
\end{align*}$$
where $|\epsilon_1|, |\epsilon_2|, |\epsilon_3| < \epsilon_m = \epsilon_{machine}$. Now distributing, we have $$\begin{align*}(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_3) &= 1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_3 + \epsilon_2 \epsilon_3\\
&=1 + \epsilon_4 
\end{align*}$$
where $|\epsilon_4| \le 2 \epsilon_m + \epsilon_m^2 \le 3 \epsilon_m$, if $\epsilon_m < 1.$ Similarly, $(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_3) \le 1 + \epsilon_5$ where  $\epsilon_5 \le 3 \epsilon_m$ if $\epsilon_m \le 1.$

Thus \begin{align*}
\tilde f(x, y) = x(1 + \epsilon_4) - y(1 + \epsilon_5) = f(\tilde x, \tilde y).
\end{align*}

Now here's they key part. Using the 2-norm, the relative error is
$$\frac {||(x, y) - (\tilde x, \tilde y)||}{||(x, y)||} = \frac {||(\epsilon_4, \epsilon_5)||}{||(x, y)||} \le \frac {3 \sqrt2}{||(x-y)||} \epsilon_m = c(x, y) \epsilon_m$$
The problem is that the coefficient of $\epsilon_m$ above depends on the input $(x, y)$. There doesn't exist one $x$ that works for all $(x, y)$. But this is what is needed for backward stability. So why is subtraction backward stable?

Comment: Take a closer look at the subtraction $(x,y)-(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$. You lost something important there.

Comment: @CarlChristian Ohhhh wow thank you so much! I was going crazy verifying the other steps.

Comment: You are very welcome. We have all been there. Repeatedly.

Comment: Please do not cross-post, and if you can not resist, please do link the other locations on both ends. Here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40316/why-is-subtraction-a-stable-operation already has answers, and the comment above by Carl Christian would have avoided duplicate effort on the other site, or at least focused these answers more precisely.